# Having trouble defining a function that will make creating a dictionary easier

Tags: python, dictionary, debugging

I am trying to create a `player_def` function that will make creating a dictionary a little easier.

Looking at it now, this is probably kind of dumb because I can just do `players["betts"]["avg"]=340`, right? Anyway, to understand how Python works I would be grateful if any of you can explain why the following code is returning a key error instead of creating a nested dictionary.

```
def player_def(x,y,z):
  players[x][y]=z
player_def("betts","avg",340)
print(players["betts"])
```

Comment: First, you have to specify that the `players` variable is a dictionary type. Only then can you add any items to the dictionary. This is done by direct declaration of the variable with `players = dict()` or by assigning an empty dictionary to the variable, i.e. `players = {}`. However, you are adding a dictionary pair `{a:b}` to a variable that does not exist yet. In addition, you want to use a nested dictionary (dictionary in the dictionary ...or... a two-dimensional data field). This makes the situation more complicated. Try using the Python Console to test the functionality.

Comment: @ajeferson thank you. I did already have players defined as a dictionary earlier in the code. I only posted the part I considered relevant.

Comment: All right, then show me how you have this variable declared. What exactly do you really want to explain? I do not understand, sorry.

Comment: @GaryPalstor sorry about the wrong editing. Just redid it. Good luck!

Comment: @s3n0

I wrote

from player_dict_ import players and then players is defined with a big block of code that I do not know how to put in a comment here. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

players = defaultdict(dict)

def player_def(x,y,z):
    players[x][y] = z

player_def("betts","avg",340)
print(players["betts"])
# {'avg': 340}
```

We define `players` as a `defaultdict` of `dict`. When we do:

```
players["betts"]["avg"] = 340
```

if `players` doesn't yet have a `betts` key, a new one is created on the fly with an empty `dict` as value. So, we can add `"avg": 340` to this new dict.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Python. Can you explain what the defaultdict function is doing in this instance?

Comment: Hey I tried the

players["betts"]["avg"] = 340

and it returned a keyerror for "betts," apparently not creating a key within the dictionary "players."

Also, I am not sure how to format comments better so the code is in courier or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? I'm sorry, but my query does not respond to your problem in a comment, so I had to put it as a possible solution / explanation.

```
>>> d={}
>>> d
{}
>>> d['a'] = {'b' : {'c','d','e'} }
>>> d
{'a': {'b': {'c', 'e', 'd'}}}
>>>
>>> d['a']['b']
{'c', 'e', 'd'}
```

///EDIT: So when the dictionary already exists, then you can change its contents. However, if you want to add a new pair (to the right side of an existing key), you must add to the existing key, a non-existent, just above syntax. I guess I explain that complicated, sorry.

```
>>> d['a']['b'] = "4"
>>> d
{'a': {'b': '4'}}
>>> d['a']['b'] = ["4","test","hello"]
>>> d
{'a': {'b': ['4', 'test', 'hello']}}
>>> d['a']['b'] = (1,2,3,4)
>>> d
{'a': {'b': (1, 2, 3, 4)}}
>>>
```

Another example from Python console:

```
>>> test = {}
>>> test['betts']['avg'] = 300
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'betts'
>>> test['betts'] = {}
>>> test['betts']['avg'] = 300
>>> test
{'betts': {'avg': 300}}
>>>
```

Comment: It seems that players["betts"]={"avg":340} works to define the variable but players["betts"]["avg"]=340 does not. Do you know why?

Sorry, not exactly a reply to your question, but I am using the logic you used in line 4 of that code.